# How to mock an interface with junit in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, junit4

I'm trying to test a method which throws different exceptions according to the messages in the exceptions it receives.

I'm having a hard time throwing a SOAPFaultException because its constructor expects a SOAPFault which is an interface.

So I need to mock an interface or a different approach. This project uses grails 2.2.4 and junit 4.10.

Any help is appreciated.

The code:

```
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException

class CatalogClientService {
    AplicacaoPT aplicacaoPT = new AplicacaoSoapService().getAplicacaoSoapPort()
    static transactional = false

    def fetch(String codigoBuscado) { 
        try {
            def response = aplicacaoPT.buscaAplicacaoPorCodigo(codigoBuscado)

            def app = response[0].serviceData.aplicacao[0]
            def appGeral = app.getGeral()

            def allTags = app.palavras.palavraChave.findAll().collect { it }
            def tags = allTags.unique()

            [name: appGeral.nome, description: appGeral.descricao, tags: tags, admins: [appGeral.getLiderProjeto().getChave()]]
        } catch (SOAPFaultException e) {
            if (e.fault.faultString == "Provider Error") {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nenhuma aplicação encontrada com o código ${codigoBuscado}.", e)
            }

            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao buscar aplicação de código ${codigoBuscado}.", e)                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao buscar aplicação de código ${codigoBuscado}.", e)
        }
    }
}


import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import org.junit.*
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault

@TestFor(CatalogClientService)
class CatalogClientServiceTests {

    final shouldFailWithCause = new GroovyTestCase().&shouldFailWithCause

    void testFetchFailsWithInvalidApplicationCode() {
        def fault = new Expando()
        fault.metaClass.getFaultString = { -> "Provider Error" }
        SOAPFaultException.metaClass.'static'.getFault = { -> fault }

        AplicacaoPT.metaClass.buscaAplicacaoPorCodigo = { String id -> throw new SOAPFaultException() }

        shouldFailWithCause(SOAPFaultException) { service.fetch("POPB") }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a simple way to create an instance of SOAPFault you should be able to do something like this...

```
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault

// ...

new SOAPFaultException({} as SOAPFault)
```

If you want to provide some method implementations, like getFaultString() for example, you can do someting like this...

```
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault

// ...
def soapFault = [getFaultString: { 'some message'}] as SOAPFault
new SOAPFaultException(soapFault)
```

I hope that helps